# Ubuntu: i can't kill some processes and Apache doesn't restart

Tags: apache2, process, kill

I can't restart Apache: if I try to start it, the error is this:

```
(98)Address already in use: 
AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 
no listening sockets available, shutting down 
AH00015: Unable to open logs Action 'start' failed. 
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

If I try to stop it (even if it's not running), the error is this:

There are processes named 'apache2' running which do not match your pid file which are left untouched in the name of safety, Please review the situation by hand.

The problem is that I can't kill these processes; I tried with `sudo kill -9 #PID` but nothing happens. I check the pid file of Apache2 in run/apache2 but there is no files.

How can I solve?

Comment: In a terminal try to execute: sudo killall apache2 and then restart Apache.

Comment: @wie5Ooma thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't work. All processes are still alive

Comment: Can you please execute this command in the terminal: ps ax | grep apache and give the output of this command.

Comment: How are you trying to restart Apache?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually find the pidis of the crashed apache process

```
pidof apache2
```

Then kill the process(es) one at a time

```
sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

Then you can start Apache2 as usually :

```
sudo service apache2 start
```